# ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID after manual renewal

Tags: ssl, https, lets-encrypt

I just did a manual `certbot renew` but my website is still displaying an error regarding the certificate.

In the over hand, any idea why certbot would did the auto renewal?

I have in my crontab this line :

`15 3 * * * certbot renew --quiet`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it seems that for enabling the certificate, I had to restart nginx.

Still No clue about the auto renewal